# i want to run the next song in my data base

Tags: javascript, laravel

i made something like playlist and i want to play the play list when the button pressed and keep running
until some one stop it

```js
var i = 0;
var player = document.getElementById("player-" + i);

function playlist() {
  player.play();
}

function runnext() {
  var player = document.getElementById("player-" + i++);
  if (!player) {
    var player = document.getElementById("player-" + i++);
  }
  player.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="playlist()" onclick="playlist()">run</i></button>
<button onclick="pausemusic(this)">stop</button> @foreach($songs as $song)
<audio class="player m-auto" id="player-{{$song->id}}" src="{{asset('audios/'.$song->song)}}" type="audio/ogg" onended="runnext()" controls></audio> @endforeach
```

Comment: its laravel btw and i cant find  [<>] snippet editor

Comment: oh finally did it

Comment: Now change `@foreach($songs as $song)
<audio class="player m-auto" id="player-{{$song->id}}" src="{{asset('audios/'.$song->song)}}" type="audio/ogg" onended="runnext()" controls></audio> @endforeach` to plain HTML with 3 examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `ended` even

```
var i = 0;

function runnext() {
  var player = document.getElementById("player-" + i);
  if (!player) {
    alert('no more audio');
    return;
  }
  player.play();
  player.addEventListener('ended', runnext);
  i++;
}

runnext(); // or on button click
```

Comment: i added no if(player) becasue its not in serial id like 1,2,3,4 
it may be 1,3,6

Comment: and `player.addEventListener('ended', runnext);` can be moved outside the runnext ;)

Comment: after each song say no more audio

Comment: check generated html and make sure your `id` is like `player-1`, `player-2`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work better - you also might want to hide the songs

```js
const audios = document.querySelectorAll("audio")
const cnt = 0;
let pause = false;
let player;


const runnext = () => {
  if (pause) return;
  player = document.getElementById(`player-${cnt}`)
  if (player) {
    player.play();
  }
}

document.getElementById("playList").addEventListener("click",runnext)
document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click",function() { pause = true; if (player) player.stop() })
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("ended",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const idx = +tgt.id.replace("player","");
  idx++;
  cnt = idx>=audios.length ? 0 : idx; // wrap to song 1
  runnext()
})
```

```html
<button id="playList" type="button" >run</i></button>
<button id="pause" type="button">stop</button> 

<div id="container">
  <audio class="player m-auto" id="player1" src="song1" type="audio/ogg" controls></audio>
  <audio class="player m-auto" id="player2" src="song2" type="audio/ogg" controls></audio>
  <audio class="player m-auto" id="player3" src="song3" type="audio/ogg" controls></audio>
</div>
```